# Datasheet assistance request

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, integrated-circuit, embedded

I'm trying to incorporate a USB-PD controller into my design for a Dual Role Port (DRP). I'm currently building with a Cypress CCG2 24-pin QFN, and using their reference block from the datasheet found [here](http://www.cypress.com/?docID=53064).

Unfortunately, I can not figure out why they have a resistor where I have marked in red circle, suggestions for this? I'm pretty sure the the symbol in the purple is P-Channel FET, can someone confirm?

Below is **Dual Role Port (DRP)** Application from page 11 of attached [datasheet](http://www.cypress.com/?docID=53064).

[image: CCG2-Datasheet-Excerpt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dampen oscillation caused by the parasitic capacitance at the gate of the FET.

Adding to this, you are correct in thinking that the symbol in purple is the P-channel FET.

Comment: What resistor value should i use?

Comment: Something small, probably 100 Ohm is fine.